# No index only scan with date conversion in index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create the following table and indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 id bigint,
 d timestamp without time zone
);

CREATE INDEX f_date4
  ON public.test
  USING btree
  (date(d), id);

CREATE INDEX f_date5
  ON public.test
  USING btree
  (id, date(d));
```

I fill the table with data and use the following query:

```
SELECT id, date(d)
FROM test
WHERE date(d) > '2019-09-20'::date;
```

`EXPLAIN` shows that f_date4 index is being used on condition `d > '2019-09-20'::date`, but i can't get `INDEX ONLY SCAN`. What are the possible reasons, why this happens and how to avoid this?

Execution plan:

```
Index Scan using f_date4 on test  (cost=0.06..0.07 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
Index Cond: (date(d) > '2019-01-20'::date)
Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning time: 0.131 ms
Execution time: 0.025 ms
```

I use postgresql 10.6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited my question and added a plan. there are no more indexes. Its a test table, created for the purpose of question. It has 1000 rows. The same happens on the table with about 100 million rows.

Comment: Unrelated but why wouldn't you just do `WHERE d > '2019-09-20'::TIMESTAMP`, then you wouldn't need bother with all these date conversions.

Comment: @404 an index on a truncated timestamp does not make much sense, either. and `WHERE d >= '2019-09-21'` would suffice, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

An index on the complete timestamp can serve the same purposes as one the *truncated* timestamp.

---

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
 d timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test(d)
select gs FROM generate_series('2019-01-01'::timestamp,'2020-01-01'::timestamp,'4 hour':: interval) gs
        ;

CREATE INDEX f_date4
  ON test
  USING btree (d, id);

CREATE INDEX f_date5
  ON test
  USING btree (id, d);


VACUUM ANALYZE test;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT id, d::date
FROM test
WHERE d >= '2019-09-21' -- NOTE: slightly changed condition
        ;

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2191
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
VACUUM
```

---

Resulting query plan:

---

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using f_date4 on test  (cost=0.28..17.32 rows=612 width=12) (actual time=0.025..0.160 rows=613 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (d >= '2019-09-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
   Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.285 ms
 Execution Time: 0.218 ms
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-index-only-scans.html) say:

> However, PostgreSQL's planner is currently not very smart about such cases.

The summary is that one part of the planner thinks it needs "d" to compute `date(d)` even though another part realizes it already has `date(d)`.  Getting those two parts to communicate is not easy.

You can build the index `(date(d), id,d)` to get around this.